# Acl vs RBAC in ZF2

Tags: php, security, zend-framework2, zend-acl, zfc-rbac

I want to incorporate a component of access control in my application, I saw that ZF2 offer: `Zend /permissions/Acl` and `Zend /permissions/RBAC`, I would like to know which is more efficient and secured , and what about `Zfc-RBAC` ?
thank you .

Comment: I haven't use RBAC but they seem basically the same, however on the comments section at http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.permissions.rbac.intro.html - they said something about that this was removed from the repository. So I don't know if that's actually true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It totally depends on your needs. `Rbac` is Access Control managed by permissions on merely roles, where `Acl` is a solution where you will be managing both resources and roles. The Rbac of Zend Framework 2  has some complexities that are going to be simplified in ZF3.

If you consider using Rbac I would suggest to check `zfc-rbac` from `zf-commons` which is built on top of the prototype for ZF3's Rbac.

[**Here on GitHub**](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac) you can find `zfc-rbac`.

If you consider Acl I would suggest to take a look at `BjyAuthorize` which can be found [**here**](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize)